# Split a single column into two

Tags: python, bash, awk

The data format I have is as follows:

```
###John###
someData1
someData2
SomeData3
###Mike###
someData1
someData2
###Ford###
someData1
someData2
SomeData3
someData4
someData5
SomeData6
```

I want the output to be:

```
John  someData1
      someData2
      someData3

Mike  someData1
      someData2

Ford  someData1
      someData2
      someData3
      someData4
      someData5
      someData6
```

The problem here is the number of data *(somedata?)* beneath each name differs and is not pre known. The only piece I've to work with is the leading `###` characters that signifies the beginning of a new name.

`Somedata?` is a single word. Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives the exact output required:

```
from sys import stdout

with open('file') as f:
    for n,line in enumerate(f):        
        if line.startswith('###'):            
            stdout.write(('' if not n else '\n')+line.strip('#\n'))
        else:
            stdout.write('\t'+line)
```

Output:

```
John    someData1
        someData2
        SomeData3

Mike    someData1
        someData2

Ford    someData1
        someData2
        SomeData3
        someData4
        someData5
        SomeData6
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use something like:

```
def fixup(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for x in it:
        if x.startswith('###'):
            yield '\n{0}\t{1}'.format(x.strip('#'),next(it))
        else:
            yield '\t{0}'.format(x)
```

This'll give you an extra newline on the first line, but that can easily be stripped off if you really want to.

Comment: or use `x.strip('#')` instead of the `.replace()` :-)

Answer (score 2):

Awk is perfect for this:

```
$ awk '/^#/{gsub(/#/,"");printf "%s",NR!=1?"\n"$0:$0;next}{print "\t"$0}' file
John    someData1
        someData2
        SomeData3

Mike    someData1
        someData2

Ford    someData1
        someData2
        SomeData3
        someData4
        someData5
        SomeData6
```

It seems `awk` on `Mac` doesn't support the ternary operator `? :` so use this `Mac` friendly version instead:

```
$ awk '/^#/{gsub(/#/,"");printf n"%s",$0;n="\n";next}{print "\t"$0}' file
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? It throws me an error saying `syntax error at source line 1... /^#/{gsub(/#/,"");printf >>>  "%s",NR!= <<<`

Comment: As sure as you can be, see here http://ideone.com/5Ca8za What platform are you on and what version of `awk` do you have?

Comment: `$awk -version` gives awk version 20070501. It still gives me the same error.

Comment: You seem to have old/broken `awk` are you on Solaris? You need to use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` instead.

Comment: That is very strange. I'm on a macOSX 10.8.3.

Comment: @Sunil interesting, I logged into a mac machine, it doesn't like the ternary operator, I have added a mac friendly answer but I suggest you install `GNU awk` :]

Answer (score 2):

An itertools approach:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('yourfile') as fin:
    for k, g in groupby(fin, lambda L: L.startswith('###')):
        if k:
            name = next(g).strip('#\n')
        else:
            print '{}\t{}'.format(name, next(g)),
            for line in g:
                print '\t{}'.format(line),
            print
```

Comment: Groups don't get separated by an empty line.

Comment: @sunil then just add a `print` - can't edit post as on mobile at the mo'

Answer (score 0):

You can easily split your data with re.split

```
import re
namesInfo = re.split('###(.*?)###', dataString)
```

Then you get an array of names followed by the associated data.
You can then parse the data for each name.